# Embedded form on one TPanel Using TCustomForm

Tags: delphi

I´m having problems passing the componentes from one form to a panel, like embedded.
This is part of the code i´m using :

```
for I := 0 to Length(Modules)-1 do
begin
  if Modules[i].PHandle<>0 then
   begin
     @p:=GetProcAddress(Modules[i].PHandle,'GetBaseControl');
     if Assigned(p) then
      begin
        LogToFile( self, 'Criar Form externo de package...', '' , '' );
        Form:=p('TFrmRetailPOS');
        EmbeddForm(MainPanel,Form,True);
        Modules[i].BaseControl:=Form;
        Break;
      end;
   end;
end;
```

The EmbeddForm procedure is this :

```
procedure EmbeddForm(AParent:TFmxObject; AForm:TCustomForm ; CreateAForm : 
Boolean);
begin
  LogToFile( nil, 'EmbeddForm Start' , '' , '' );
  If CreateAForm then AForm:=TCustomForm.CreateNew(Application.MainForm)
  else LogToFile( nil, 'EmbeddForm não cria FORM' , '' , '' );

  LogToFile( nil, 'EmbeddForm = '+Aform.Caption , '' , '' );

  LogToFile( nil, 'EmbeddForm ChildrenCount = '+IntToStr(AForm.ChildrenCount) , '' , '' );

  while AForm.ChildrenCount>0 do
   begin
    LogToFile( nil, 'EmbeddForm Pass ['+AForm.Children[0].Name+']' , '' , '' );
    AForm.Children[0].Parent:=AParent;
   end;
end;
```

The p function is like this :

```
Function GetBaseControl ( ClassName : String ) : TCustomForm; StdCall; Export ;
Var AClass : TPersistentClass;
Begin

  AClass:=TPersistentClass(FindAnyClass(ClassName));

  if AClass<>nil then
   begin
    LogToFile( nil, 'Criou Class Form ['+ClassName+']' , '' , '' );
    Result:=TComponentClass(AClass).Create(Application) as TCustomForm;
   end
  else LogToFile( nil, 'NÃO encontroi Class Form ['+ClassName+']' , '' , '' );
End;
```

The class form i´m trying to push is registered like this on the package that´s in :

```
initialization
  RegisterClass (TFrmRetailPOS);

finalization
  UnRegisterClass(TFrmRetailPOS);
```

I have some text logs on the form ONCreate of that form to see, and its created correctly. The problem is the "AForm" variable does not have any components on it. The children count is zero. This comes from a dynamic loaded package. I´m using delphi 10.2 .
What am i doing wrong ?!

Thanks.

Comment: I detected my problem... I was beeing and idiot lol. I was creating a new instance of TCustomform in                                                                            If CreateAForm then AForm:=TCustomForm.CreateNew(Application.MainForm)

Answer (score -3):

I was creating a new instance of TCustomform in

```
If CreateAForm then AForm:=TCustomForm.CreateNew(Application.MainForm)
```

thats why it was empty lol...
Sorry

Comment: The answer can't be in code not in the question. It's not about mind reading. Best delete the entire post.